# How to transfer milliseconds from POSIXct to another POSIXct based on a third column in r

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I have around 50 unique events that occur more than once during the day. The solution should go through the events checking if their start time refers to them in the `timestamp` column. Since the `timestamp` stores, both `start` and `end` time. And there are, some of the events can occur one after another having a different starting time and a different ending time.

I have a hard time figuring out the following:

I have a tibble with:
`timestamp` contains the exact beginning and the exact end of an event down to milliseconds, so both `start` and `stop` are in `timestamp`
`start` column contains the beginning of the event without the milliseconds
`stop` column contains the end of the event down to milliseconds
`event` column contains the name of the event

I would like to transfer the milliseconds from `timestamp`, for when the event started, to the `start` column for the particular event that started in the `start` column.

```
   options(digits.secs=3)
   timestamp <- as.POSIXct(c("2019-01-07 06:05:23.582 CET", "2019-01-07 06:05:23.582 CET", "2019-01-07 06:05:23.582 CET",
               "2019-01-07 06:05:43.967 CET", "2019-01-07 06:05:43.967 CET", "2019-01-07 06:05:43.967 CET",
               "2019-01-07 06:05:45.026 CET","2019-01-07 06:07:10.463 CET", "2019-01-07 06:07:10.463 CET",
               "2019-01-07 06:07:18.467 CET"))

   start <- as.POSIXct(c("2019-01-07 06:05:23 CET", "2019-01-07 06:05:23 CET", "2019-01-07 06:05:23 CET", "2019-01-07 06:05:23 CET",
          "2019-01-07 06:05:23 CET", "2019-01-07 06:05:23 CET", "2019-01-07 06:05:23 CET", "2019-01-07 06:07:10 CET",
          "2019-01-07 06:07:10 CET", "2019-01-07 06:07:10 CET"))

   stop <- as.POSIXct(c(NA, NA, NA, "2019-01-07 06:05:43.967 CET", NA, "2019-01-07 06:05:43.967 CET",
         "2019-01-07 06:05:45.026 CET", NA, NA, "2019-01-07 06:07:18.467 CET"))

   event <- c("A",    "A",  "B", "A",   "B", "A",   "B", "C", "B", "B")

   df <- tibble(timestamp = timestamp, start = start, stop = stop, event = event)
   df
```

The end goal is the following table:

```
      start                    stop                    event
      <dttm>                   <dttm>                  <chr>
    1 2019-01-07 06:05:23.582  2019-01-07 06:05:43.967  A    
    2 2019-01-07 06:05:23.582  2019-01-07 06:05:45.026  B    
    3 2019-01-07 06:07:10.463  2019-01-07 06:07:18.467  B
```

The milliseconds for the beginning of the event transferred from `timestamp` to `start` column. 
In my case, the event A has two occurrences with the exact same start and stop down to milliseconds, so only one event is needed.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this can improved upon, but seems to do what you asked:

```
library(lubridate); library(dplyr)
df %>%
  # Add to the original table...
  inner_join(
    # based on a lookup table connecting the rounded starts with "real start"
    df %>% 
      mutate(real_start = if_else(timestamp %>% floor_date("seconds") == start,
                          timestamp, ymd_h(NA_real_))) %>%
      select(start, real_start) %>%
      tidyr::drop_na()
  ) %>%
  tidyr::drop_na() %>%
  distinct(event, real_start, stop)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  event real_start              stop                   
  <chr> <dttm>                  <dttm>                 
1 A     2019-01-07 06:05:23.582 2019-01-07 06:05:43.967
2 B     2019-01-07 06:05:23.582 2019-01-07 06:05:45.026
3 B     2019-01-07 06:07:10.463 2019-01-07 06:07:18.467
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't go through the events checking if their start time refers to them in the `timestamp` column. Since the timestamp stores, both start end time.

Comment: Not sure I understand. `real_start = if_else(timestamp %>% floor_date("seconds") == start,` checks to see if the truncated version of timestamp matches `start`, and if so it uses the more precise number. That's then joined to the original, so we see the `real_start` column which uses the timestamp number and seems to match your desired output.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, the whole day I was trying to figure it out. Your solution is correct. The problem is not your approach but rather the way the data is stored - it is so that the `timestamp` column happened to be not the reference column for `start` or `stop`, on top of that some events don't have a `start` time or a `stop` time. When I tried to do a backcheck - I got confused by the results. Initially, I thought that the problem was the approach,  but, no, it is not. Anyway, I am sorry for this and thank you for replying. -All the best